# Is there any way to export a list of all email addresses a particular user has sent to using powershell?

Tags: email, exchange, contacts

We have a lady at a company we support who is leaving and she would like to send a 'goodbye' email to everyone she has mailed in the past. She has not biult up a contacts list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what version of Exchange Server you're running but the only way you could do this would be if you have logging enabled, have all of the logs from the beginning of time (from the time since this user started using Exchange), and you'd have to parse all of your logs to find where this user was the sender and then extract the recipient information from those log entries.

Alternately, if the user has the option set to save a copy of sent emails in the Sent Items folder, you could extract the information from there, but I don't see that being a quick or easy task.

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't think message logging has been enabled, I was just hoping there would be some way of interrogating her sent folder for addresses using Powershell. It is Exchange 2007. I'm sorry if I'm being an idiot here.